# issues with editing embeds through modals in discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

i've created this embed system, since mimu only allows a few embeds but im having a problem. Any time i would edit the footer text then re-click the button to edit the timestamp, it removes the footer text instead of just removing the timestamp.

and im also having trouble setting the color for the embed when i go to click the button and enter all of the relevant information for the embed color everything goes through but the color is never updated with no errors raised.

for the timestamp and footer text issue:

```
            embed.set_footer(text=self.ftext.value, icon_url=self.fticon.value)
        elif not self.time:
            embed.set_footer()
        
        if self.time.value.lower() == "yes":
            embed.timestamp = datetime.now()
        elif not self.ftext:
            embed.timestamp = None
```

```
        if self.ftext:
            embed.set_footer(text=self.ftext.value, icon_url=self.fticon.value)
        else:
            embed.set_footer(text=None, icon_url=None)
        
        if self.time.value.lower() == "yes":
            embed.timestamp = datetime.now()
        else:
            embed.timestamp = None
```

and many more ways but any way i tried, removing the timestamp removed the text

for the hex code issue:

```
    async def on_submit(self, interaction:discord.Interaction):
        embed = interaction.message.embeds[0]
        if self.hec and isinstance(self.hec, str):
            stripped_hec = self.hec.strip("#")
            embed.color = discord.Color(int(stripped_hec, 16))
        else:
            embed.color = None

        if self.titl:
            embed.title = self.titl.value

        if self.desc:
            embed.description = self.desc.value

        await interaction.message.edit(embed=embed)
```